# Why can't I save the results of my node api call to variable and send it with Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, server

I'm using Node to make an api call to a movie database. The node api call is inside of an Express route.

```
    //require the modules I need
var express = require('express');
var router = require('./router.js');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
// var router = require('express').Router();
var newBody;

var http = require("https");

//init app
var server = express();
server.set('port', 8080); 

//attach middleware
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
server.use(bodyParser.json())

//direct to home page
server.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../client'));

// start listening to requests on port 8000
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 8000);

console.log("listening to 8000")

// server.use(router);



server.post('/stars', function (req, res) {
    //working
    console.log('in STARS-server(server)!!!');
    console.log('req.body', req.body);
    var actor = req.body.actor;
    var uriActor = encodeURI(actor);
    console.log('actor', actor, 'uriActor', uriActor);

    var myPerson = uriActor;
    var myPath = "/3/search/person?include_adult=false&page=1&query=" + myPerson + "&language=en-US&api_key=my api key";

    var options = {
      "method": "GET",
      "hostname": "api.themoviedb.org",
      "port": null,
      "path": myPath,
      "headers": {}
    };
```

Here's my node http request:

```
    var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
      var chunks = [];


      res.on("data", function (chunk) {
        chunks.push(chunk);
      });

      res.on("end", function () {
        var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
         newBody = body.toString()
        console.log("poststring", newBody);         
      });
    });
        console.log("API response body1", newBody);
     req.write("{}");
     req.end();
     //console.log('res', res, 'req', req);


     console.log("BOOOOOOOOODY", newBody)
    res.send();
    console.log("BoOooooody2", newBody);
});
```

That newBody variable inside of res.on("end") logs all of the information that I need to send back. But when I try to console log new body at the bottom, it comes back as undefined. Is this an Asynchronous error? How would I fix it? Is there a better way to write the api request in Express?

Comment: The `.on("end"...`  handler is async, you're outputting the `newBody` variable before it has content.

Comment: @adeneo Yeah. You're totally right. How do I wait for it, so it has content?

Comment: Do all of your express sending within the on "end" callback itself.  That's what it's there for.  You are going to need to change some of your variable naming so you can access the Express res variable within the callback.

Comment: This is because the data arrives asynchronously, some time in the future.  Meanwhile the rest of your code has already finished running before the response arrives and `res.on("end", ...)` is triggered.  You have to use the result inside of `res.on("end", ...)`, nowhere else.  FYI, you are one of thousands of folks here on stack overflow that have a similar issue understanding asynchronous responses when they first start working with node.js.  There are probably more than a thousand answers here discussing various flavors of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
http.get(options, function(response) {
    var body = '';
    response.on('data', function(d) {
        body += d;
    });
    response.on('end', function() {
        console.log(body);
        res.send(body);
    });
});
```